# How should I approach Wittgenstein's works?

Tags: logic, reference-request, wittgenstein

I recently read Ray Monk's excellent biography of Wittgenstein, and would like to read something by the Austrian philosopher himself. It seems that you need to know a fair amount of logic to start with. I've taken college philosophy classes before (including logic), but they seem too easy and are not much of help here. So what are some texts you would recommend to study before reading Wittgenstein? Thanks!

Edit: I'm not confining the scope to logic books only. I thought that was the part I didn't understand, but it could very possibly be wrong. Also, if possible, could you recommend books that do not directly concern Wittgenstein but will be helpful?

Comment: *Tractatus* is difficult but not so much for uts "logical" content. You can read e.g. M.Morris, [Routledge Philosophy GuideBook to Wittgenstein and the Tractatus](https://books.google.it/books?id=_zJ-AgAAQBAJ).

Comment: Maybe usefule on Youtube: [The Logic of Wittgenstein's Tractatus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e75U1fgBC6g)

Comment: Related post: [what-is-the-logic-in-the-tractatus-logico-philosophicus-in-modern-terms](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/5942/what-is-the-logic-in-the-tractatus-logico-philosophicus-in-modern-terms)

Comment: And see [W's Tractatus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#EarlWitt) and [W's Logical Atomism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-atomism/).

Comment: Also M.Potter, *The Logic of the Tractatus*, in Dov M. Gabbay & John Woods (eds.), [Handbook of the History of Logic. Volume 5: From Russell to Church](https://books.google.it/books?id=IMgg0Uc00I4C&pg=PA255), page 255-on.

Answer (score 2):

Wittgenstein's lifetime concern was how language relates to the world. He offered two ways to answer the question: the early *Tractatus* way, and the later *Philosophical Investigation* way.

In the *Tractatus* era, Wittgenstein, still influenced by Vienna Circle and logical positivism, regarded the world as being composed of atomic facts. He thought that there was a one-to-one correspondence between a proposition and a fact.

In the *Philosophical Investigation* era, Wittgenstein gave up on the *Tractatus* approach, and proclaimed that linguistic meaning obtains, neither through references nor through mental images, but through the use of language itself. Insofar as members of a linguistic community understand how to use a given word properly, according to him, they can be said to understand the meaning of the word.

If you want to know about the *Important* Wittgenstein, you should just read the Investigation. The work influenced many other academic fields (poli sci, sociology, e.g.).

Comment: quibble: he didn't just give up on Tractatus, he unequivocally rejected it, i believe.  It's only of historical interest today.

Comment: I think you are right. But Wittgenstein's ladder makes me hesitate to affirm your claim with enthusiasm.

Comment: hmmm. i'm inclined to think the ladder is a Tractatus ladder, which does not lead to PI.  Not so sure there is a ladder for PI, only a hermeneutcal circle.  you can throw away the ladder for Tractatus, PI is a different matter.

Comment: i wonder what LW would say.

Comment: One thing backwards here: I think it's Kraft who describes a VC member, maybe Schlick, finding Tractatus in the library, and bringing it to their reading group at the very beginning. It inspired the development of LP, not the other way around. (Hi Nanhee! I was at mn w/ you)

Comment: Thanks ChristopherE for the chronological correction. you are right. Carnap and Schlick were impressed by Tractatus, but they thought Wittgenstein was mistaken on the ladder stuff. the basic tenet of logical positivism existed in europe (frege in germany, russell in uk) prior to witt.

Comment: ChristoherE: At what circumstance at U of MN? graduate student, my student?

Answer (score 0):

Oxford University Press.
Wittgenstein A Very Short Introduction by Grayling A C
Available on ebay for about £5